# public Object from public method not visible in another public method in same class

Tags: c#, scope, visibility, public

I am a struggling newbie trying to learn and figure out this new C# language and OO style and my brain is not as sharp as 20 years ago.
Here we have a simple database connection to Access (.accdb)
I am instantiating a helper class which contains two methods i.e. makeconn and  the readfrondb methods as follows

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {

        Clshelper chelp = new Clshelper();

        chelp.makeconn(); 
        chelp.readfromdb();

    }
```

This is the helper class below - created because I want to keep the connection part and whatever type of data manipulation I do in separate methods.
However unless the line that creates a connection object con1 in the method makeconn throws an exception because the con1 is a NULL object if i code it as below.

```
public class Clshelper {
    public OleDbConnection con1;
    public OleDbCommand cmd;

    public Clshelper() {
        Console.WriteLine("instantiated Cls_helper()");
    }

    public void  makeconn() {   
       OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = D:\\DATA.accdb");
    }

    public void readfromdb() {

        con1.Open();
      (...)
      }
```

However If I place the line from makeconn that creates the con1 connection object into the top of readfromdb and only run readfromdb everything works fine.
So why isn't the readfromdb method able to "see" the con1 object i created in the makeconn method - I thought any variables in a class are visible to all methods in the that same class ??

Comment: Just change `OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(...)` to `this.con1 = new OleDbConnection(...)` to access the expected property.

Comment: consider using some naming convention that helps you identify member variables, such `m_Con1` or `_con1` (really opinion based on what convention to use, but I advice to use something different from the "simple names" used for local variables / function parameters)

Comment: You shouldn't store database connections in fields (class level variables). ADO.NET connections (such as OleDbConnection) implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) They should be created in a using block.

Comment: @mason, for a connection helper as `Clshelper` seems to be, storing the connection in a member variable (and having the class itself implement IDisposable) can be a good idea. I think .Net `OleDbConnection` class does exactly the same

Comment: @Gian Paolo (and others) does a class like my helper automatically implement iDisposable in the background or do I have to code it manually - and based on standards would the "using" approach be better ?

Comment: @GianPaolo No, it is NOT a good idea. This helper is not following a good pattern. It's not able to ensure that the connection is disposed of properly. Please read up on IDisposable so that you understand why it's necessary.

Comment: @user3511553 If your helper implements IDisposable, then you need to ensure that it disposes of the connection in the Dispose method. And you need to make sure that the helper itself is then created in a `using` block to ensure that it gets disposed properly. It's really just moving the goal posts. Rather than having a helper like this, I suggest looking into modern repository patterns with ADO.NET connections.

Comment: @Mason, thinking more at it, I agree with you. A method such `readfromdb()` should create, use and dispose its connection. I'm trying to figure out a scenario where the connection need to be used across more methods (maybe a transaction?), but cannot see it right now.

Comment: @Gian yes, transaction is a valid reason for it, you have to be very careful if you go that route to make sure it gets disposed properly.

Comment: @mason, I agree, definitely. Actually, that's true for every IDisposable object, an `using` keyword is so helpful here! As a rule of thumb, if your class store an instance of an IDisposable object, the class itself should be Disposable, should implement Dispose correctly, and it's responsibility of client code to properly dispose it.

Comment: @GianPaolo Not *every* IDisposable, but almost. [HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) is a special circumstance when you shouldn't. Then there's classes like [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) that implement IDisposable but usually don't need to be disposed of. Of course, I'd avoid DataTable at all costs anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
OleDbConnection con1 = // ...
```

actually creates a brand new variable within the scope of the `makeconn` function. While you have another class-scoped variable named `con1`, they are separated variables, so assigning a value to one (function-scoped) variable does not assign the value to the other (class-scoped) variable.

The fix is pretty easy. Rather than declaring a new variable, just use the one you've already declared in your class:

```
public void  makeconn() {
   // Don't declare a new variable here:
   con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = D:\\DATA.accdb");
}
```

---

Interesting side-note. If you have a function-scoped variable named the same as a class-scoped instance variable, you can access the class-scoped variable using the `this` keyword:

```
class MyClass {
    private int myVar = 1;

    private void myFunc(){
        int myVar = 2; // function-scoped myVar overrides class-scoped myVar

        int myOtherVar;

        myOtherVar = myVar; // myOtherVar = 2 (function-scoped myVar)
        myOtherVar = this.myVar; // myOtherVar = 1 (class-scoped myVar)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much JDB - what a silly newbie error on my part - or course the new keyword  is a declaration of a new variable / object. Was originally trying to create the connection method as a static of some sort since it always will stay the same - but it failed me so i just created everything as public - so any suggestion regarding making the connection oject or the makeconn method static are welcome improvements - great community

Answer (score 1):

Your helper class is not able to follow good practices regarding disposing connections. Eventually this can lead to exhausting the available connections. And when this happens, it's extremely difficult to track down. That's why you need to take care when working with [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects to make sure you've handled them properly.

Here's one way of following this pattern correctly:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MyRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
        using (var command = new OleDbCommand("command text", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //execute command and return results here
        }
    }

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
        using (var command = new OleDbCommand("command text", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //execute command here
        }
    }
}
```

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) (not shown here) simplifies it further so you don't have to create the command object and map the results to/from your strongly typed classes.

Comment: thanks mason - 1. is "using" recommended for connections and command objects as per your example and                                                                               2. in the industry / workplace is it acceptable to use     
 "var con1" as a shortcut instead of say "OleDbConnection con1"

Comment: I specifically showed it with the using statement because that's the correct way of doing it. The using statement will ensure that the objects get disposed of, even if there's an exception. You should do that with almost every object that implements IDisposable interface. Using `var` is a shortcut for not having to explicitly write the type, but you still have full type safety. Many companies have a coding style dictating when it can and can't be used. Learn to use it, so if you come across it you're familiar with it. And when you get to a company, see what their preferences are.

Comment: @user35 did you read the documentation I gave you the link to?